# printf ("%d", 0.0625) prints a zero while nearby values such as 0.0624 print absurd numbers as you would expect, why is 0.0625 different?

Tags: c, floating-point, integer, printf

I also noticed that multiples of 0.0625 such as 1.25 keep giving zero but I was unable to find an explanation

Comment: Any decent book, tutorial or class should have taught you that the `%d` format is for `int` values, and `0.0625` is a `double`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: try `dump(&x, sizeof x);` where `x` is a double with different values and `dump()` is a function you can write to examine the contents of memory.

Comment: Yeah that much I understand, perhaps I wasn't clear in how I formatted my question.

I wanted to know how come certain numbers give zero. I would've expected all numbers to give strange numbers but there must be a rhyme or reason as for why multiples of that number give zero.

I don't know if I explained clearly.

to put it another way, multiple of 0.0625 giving zero strucks me as interesting since it looks neat in comparison the other undefined behavior, I wondered what mechanism is behind this conversion

Comment: Maybe `printf()` thinks `int` are received in registers... but as you used a double in your source the compiler didn't use the correct register for `printf()`

Comment: Do you know how IEEE 754 works? The numbers which you say "give 0" are multiples of a not too negative negative power of 2. So when you store them in little endian, the 32 less significant bits, that are all 0, are the first thing you find in memory as int. Your int is 32 bits wide, thus 0.

Comment: @CostantinoGrana Oh I see, I understand now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per CostantinoGrana

> "Do you know how IEEE 754 works? The numbers which you say "give 0"
> are multiples of a not too negative negative power of 2. So when you
> store them in little endian, the 32 less significant bits, that are
> all 0, are the first thing you find in memory as int. Your int is 32
> bits wide, thus 0."